# AngularJS: test $scope methods that make async calls

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine, promise

I'm trying to test a controller method I have on the $scope. That method makes an async call and get a promise back. When the promise is resolved, the result is assign to a variable on the $scope.

The test I'm trying to come up with is simple: assign null to the $scope variable, call the method, wait for the call to finish, expect the result to be assign to the $scope variable.

For some reason, the promise never resolves. See http://plnkr.co/edit/qxs5Y54NvhA24Fk4MPv2?p=preview

Here is the controller method:

```
$scope.getSomething = ->
      someFactory.find().then (response) ->
        $scope.newValues = response.data
```

Now this is how I'm trying to test it:

```
  it 'should get something', ->
    scope.newValues = {}
    scope.getSomething()
    expect(scope.newValues.someData).toBeDefined()
```

For the purpose of the unit test, I'm mocking "someFactory" using the $q.when() method which, as far as I believe, should resolve immediately when passed an object. There's really no wait needed here. This is the mock factory:

```
mockSomeFactory = ($q) ->
  {
    find: ->
      $q.when {someData: true}
  }
```

And injecting it into the controller using $provide:

```
  beforeEach module 'myAngularApp', ($provide) ->
    $provide.factory "someFactory", mockSomeFactory
    return
```

I tried to use Jasmine's runs, waits and waitsFor methods but no luck. WaitsFor would always fail, even after 5000 milliseconds. See http://plnkr.co/edit/s2OL56jVCRK0Ecyycoz0?p=preview

Anyone had this happen before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular promises are only resolved during the digest cycle.
if you call $rootScope.apply() the promise should resolve.

```
root.$apply()
expect(scope.newValues.data).toBeDefined()
```

You also needed to change the name of a variable: I updated the code http://plnkr.co/edit/dB6zTpZ1jYXOO1kGAYvb?p=preview

Using data to be consitant.

```
    $scope.newValues.data = response.data

# mock factory
mockSomeFactory = ($q) ->
{
  find: ->
    $q.when {data: true}
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Thanks for fixing the plunkr as well. I'm gonna read the documentation regarding the rootScope and $apply() now.

Comment: No problem. You probably should also check out the $q documentation, the explanation of this can be seen here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q#description_differences-between-kris-kowals-q-and-$q

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get that particular unit test working with just scope.$digest() actually, instead of root.$apply().

Comment: Actually as @Blaiz mentioned, the correct way to trigger a digest cycle is by using the `$digest` function.

Comment: From the docs on $scope: Usually, you don't call $digest() directly in controllers or in directives. Instead, you should call $apply() (typically from within a directive), which will force a $digest().
I figure either is fine for a test.